# Changing the end of a number

Tags: javascript

I am having some serious trouble with my script... for some reason the console isn't talking to me and my output isn't showing up... What I'm trying to do here is get the output to be a thousand when the number reaches 1000 and million when the number reaches 1000000 and all the way to Quintilian. Please help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>
<button onclick="collectWood()" id="woodButton">collect wood</button>
<script>
window.addEventListener("DOMcontentLoaded", function(){
var wood = +localStorage.getItem("woodSave");
var woodOut = document.getElementById("output");
var woodbtn = document.getElementById('woodButton');

woodThousand();
woodMillion();
woodBillion();
woodTrillion();
woodQuadrillion();
woodQuintillion();

woodbtn.addEventListener("click", collectWood);

function collectWood() {
 wood +=1;
 woodOut.innerHTML = wood;
 localStorage.setItem("woodSave", wood);
 woodThousand();
 woodMillion();
 woodBillion();
 woodTrillion();
 woodQuadrillion();
 woodQuintillion();
}
function woodThousand() {
 console.log(wood);
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000) ? (wood / 1000).toFixed(2) + "Thousand":wood;
}
function woodMillion() {
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000000) ? (wood / 1000000).toFixed(2) + "Million":wood;
}
function woodBillion() {
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000000000) ? (wood / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "Billion":wood;
}
function woodTrillion() {
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000000000000) ? (wood / 1000000000000).toFixed(2) + "Trillion":wood;
}
function woodQuadrillion() {
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000000000000000) ? (wood / 1000000000000000).toFixed(2) + "Quadrillion":wood;
}
function woodQuintillion() {
 woodOut.textContent = (wood >= 1000000000000000000) ? (wood / 1000000000000000000).toFixed(2) + "Quintillion":wood;
}
setInterval(function() { 
woodThousand();
woodMillion();
woodBillion();
woodTrillion();
woodQuadrillion();
woodQuintillion();
}, 1);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, this code looks familiar from yesterday. First it's  `DOMContentLoaded` (with a capital "C"). That's why nothing happens when the page starts. Second, you don't need the `onclick="collectWood()"` becuase that is being taken care of in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Scott for being here yesterday. I tried copying your script and implementing to my own version as best i could but today the error detection by the console dident work, and should i add DOMContentLoaded to ever script beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` won't work on SO, so please see **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hb0j3nzt/19/)** for a solution. Your code had some issues:

First it's `DOMContentLoaded` (with a capital "C"). That's why nothing happens when the page starts. Second, you don't need the `onclick="collectWood()` because that is being taken care of in the JavaScript.

Probably the biggest change is that you don't need a different function for each level that the wood count gets to. One function will do (see the if/then in the Fiddle).

Comment: Thank you! I can always count on you! Thank you for helping me on this!

Comment: @LiamSperry Don't forget to up vote AND mark as the answer.